# Persisting an NSDictionary : performance of plist vs NSData serialization

Tags: iphone, ios, optimization

I am currently considering my options to improve scene load times in a game. The game is built around a home brewed scripting language, that is very convenient for defining scene logic and AI tidbits. Currently, I parse the scripts when a scene is initialized, and most of it manifests itself in-core as NSDictionaries.  The dictionaries are all 'plain vanilla' NSSomethingOrOther, all plist'able.

As mentioned, persisting these dictionaries once, and storing the resulting data in the resource bundle, would certainly eliminate the intensive CPU requirement of parsing for syntax and semantics. So an improvement would be the net difference between a clean parse at scene instantiation vs reloading the resulting dictionaries from disk. I was wondering whether the dictionary's recovery from disk would benefit (or lose), from a performance standpoint, from being serialized/deserialized in an NSData. I have all the time in the world to write-out the dictionaries, a one time operation at the end of the packaging cycle for the game.

any thoughts ?

Comment: @James Webster : force of habit, I highly value the opinions/inputs from some peers who socialize in the cocos2d-iphone tag :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be rather easy to test empirically?

Comment: @claireware : possibly, if i had the NSData serDes handy. As I said, I am 'considering' ... I am trying to get a feel for whether i will spend the time to build/test/build/test that abstraction layer. I will probably end-up writing a 'do it quick' serDes for one of the hefty dictionaries, and see what gives.